# Problem getting value from vue component and submit

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel.
I'm trying to submit month picker value, but can't find a way to get the value from calendar. When submitted, i get `/user/setdate 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`.

I've already set in route `Route::post('/user/setdate', 'UserController@setDate');`

Here's my calendar.vue component.

```js
    <script>
      import moment from 'moment';
      moment.locale('pt-pt');
      import VueMonthlyPicker from 'vue-monthly-picker';
      var d = new Date(),
        minDate = new Date(),
        minDate = minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - 1);
        console.log(minDate);
      export default {
        data: function() {
          return {
            monthLabels: moment.monthsShort(),
            selectedMonth: moment(new Date()),
            placeHolder: "Selecionar",
            min: moment(minDate),
            dateFormat: "MMM/YY",
            clearOption: false,
            fields: {},
            errors: {},
          }
        },
        methods: {
          submit() {
            this.errors = {};
            axios.post('/user/setdate', this.selectedMonth).then(response => {
              alert('Guardado!');
            }).catch(error => {
              if (error.response.status === 422) {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
              }
            });
          },
        },
        components: {
          VueMonthlyPicker
        },
        mounted() {
          console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
      }
    </script>
    <template>
        <form class="form-inline" @submit.prevent="submit">
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
                <vue-monthly-picker v-model="selectedMonth" :monthLabels="monthLabels" :min="min" :dateFormat="dateFormat" :placeHolder="placeHolder" :clearOption="clearOption"></vue-monthly-picker>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-2 mb-2" type="submit">Guardar</button>
        </form>
    </template>
```

When using Vue Devtools, here's the data in  element:
[image: mycalendar data]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error message did you get? What's the value of ```selectedMonth``` when you send it? (By the way, and related to the last question, do you use Vue Devtools?)

Comment: Can we see your setDate method in UserController? I think that problem is in validation of data.

Comment: Yes, I use Vue Devtools. I've updated my question with vue devtools data for the element MyCalendar.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find the problem. Was mainly because of controller validation. Because I didn't set a key in post data, I couldn't get the value in my controller for validation. I 've updated with key date `{date: this.selectedMonth}` and now i get date in controller and validate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem like N. Djokic said, was mainly because of validation in my calendar.

I was validating wrong name field when there was no request name set in post `axios.post('/user/setdate', this.selectedMonth)`

```
        $this->validate($request, [
        'selectedMonth' => 'required|string',
    ]);
```

I've updated submit method in vue with a name for the field:

```
  submit() {
    let self = this;
    self.errors = {};
    axios.post('/user/setdate', {date: this.selectedMonth}).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      alert('Guardado!');
    }).catch(error => {
      if (error.response.status === 422) {
        self.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
      }
    });
  },
```

and now I can get and validate in my controller:

```
public function setDate(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'date' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    /*
      Add mail functionality here.
    */
    return response()->json($request->input('date'), 200);
}
```